# Can I embed HTML formatting inside of a <textarea> tag?

Tags: html

If I have a `textarea` block like so...

```
<textarea name="myTextArea" cols="100" rows="20" readonly=readonly>
.. text area content ...
</textarea>
```

How can I embed HTML formatted text inside this text block?  If I can I had figured the following should work...

```
<textarea name="myTextArea" cols="100" rows="20" readonly=readonly>
<b>Hello how are you today?</b>
</textarea>
```

As an example.  But that sentence does not show up as bold.  Maybe I'm just trying to do something that can't be done?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I am pretty sure the answer is no -- cannot do it with a textarea.

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea):

> The HTML <textarea> element represents a multi-line plain-text editing control.
>
> - Permitted content Text

Answer (score 21):

Is not possible with

```
<textarea>
```

Use this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
</div>
```

Comment: This allows to edit the content of a ```div``` but doesn't allow to display the content as rendered HTML. Try to type ```<b>aoba</b>``` there and it will not display as **bold**.

Comment: It won't render on the fly (like a WYSIWYG editor might do), but you sure can do `<div contenteditable="true">Something in <i>italic</i>.</div>`

Answer (score 8):

You are correct, it cannot be done.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea), "[character data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData)" is the only permitted content for a `<textarea>`.

As other answers have described, what you are looking for is a WYSIWYG editor, like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/), or Kendo's [Editor](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/index).

This is beside the point, but interestingly, MDN lists some examples on their [HTMLTextAreaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) page on how to [enable dynamic adding of HTML tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement#Insert_HTML_tags_example) around text in a `<textarea>` and how to [enable autogrow behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement#Autogrowing_textarea_example) for a `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this (convert the "special" characters):

```
<textarea name="myTextArea" cols="100" rows="20" readonly=readonly>
&lt;b&gt;Hello how are you today?&lt;/b&gt;
</textarea>
```

Comment: Yeh that doesn't work for me.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question then.  I thought you wanted to see the HTML tags.

Answer (score 4):

Nope! If you validated that in an HTML document, you'd get an error along the lines of

> document type does not allow element "b" here

What you might be looking for is a What-You-See-Is-What-You-Get editor, which is actually an `<iframe>` which is making use of a JavaScript feature `designMode`. It's possible to find [tutorials on how to create these](http://www.devguru.com/features/tutorials/wysiwyg/wysiwyg1.asp) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20100302145650/http://www.devguru.com:80/features/tutorials/wysiwyg/wysiwyg1.asp)), but it's a much, much better idea to use an existing one, as for it to be really useful and usable takes a lot of work.

Take note that - if you were still interested in validation, which you should be if you're working with HTML - is that you won't be able to use a strict `DOCTYPE` declaration, as the WYSIWYG editor will be using an `iframe`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this too its simple and if you are using asp.net use lable contron in text area add this as

```
Text="&lt; stonename &gt;" 
"&lt";stonename"&gt";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that inside textarea but what you can do...you can use p tag and parse information to tag by JQuery. Something like this:

```
    var stringviewinfo ="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<b>aaaaaaaa</b>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaa<font color=\"red\">AAAA</font>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<b>aaaaaaaaaaaaa<b>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</br>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";      
$('#viewinfo').html(stringviewinfo);
<p style="word-wrap: break-word;" id="viewinfo"></p>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: In plain JavaScript: `var stringviewinfo = "..."; document.getElementById("viewinfo").innerHTML = stringviewinfo;`.

Comment: Note for people new to this: Always remember whenever you do something like this, if you are getting the HTML string from a user, they can choose any string they want, which might break your own HTML (especially if you save the string on a server, and so allow the user to choose arbitrary code that runs on _other people's_ browsers, this can be a security risk). See [Cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). So you need to limit what the string is allowed to be, so it will behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

By now (8 years later) you know textarea is not the way to go.
If you happen to be using Vue.js, you can use a div with v-html to set the inner HTML

```
<template>
    <div name="myTextArea" cols="100" rows="20" readonly=readonly v-html="content" />
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return{
                content = "<b>Hello how are you today?</b>";
            }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.

Use this function.

```
function br2nl(varTest) {
        return varTest.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/ig, "\r");
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a very simple way you can achieve that.

**First: Customize the `<textarea>` to accept and save special chars to DB**

`<textarea contenteditable="true" class="form-control" name="setting[header_code]"><?php echo set_value('setting[header_code]', html_entity_decode($item->header_code)) ?></textarea>`

**Second: extract and echo the saved data from DB**

`<?php echo html_entity_decode(config(nl2br('header_code')));?>`

Hope it can help you.

Thanks

Comment: This question is about HTML, php is not relevant here. Encoding HTML characters is not what the question is asking about.