# escaping/stripping html tags in internet explorer

Tags: php, html, escaping, html-escape-characters

I have implemented a template (in html and php), by which I can edit the text in some (inputs and textareas).

After I have editet the text, I store it in mysql database and I can call this template later. Now when I call this text, which I have stored in mysqldatabase, in internet exploerer, the text will be called with its html tags, I can see something like this in the textarea:

```
p> this is paragraph.</p>
```

How to tell internet explorer, that `<p></p>` and other html tags are html tags?

It works in firefox.

Comment: It's a little hard to work out exactly what your problem is, but have you tried passing it through [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) when outputting it?

Answer (score 0):

You want the tags to be visible as text?

use the function `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()`

this will convert entities to their html escape characters

read more here http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure as to what you are asking, but this is how I am understanding your question:

**How can I display HTML markup in a textarea?**

If that is the question, the answer is that you cannot. `Textarea` in standard HTML cannot display markup. It will display anything within as plain text. This is why the textarea shows your HTML tags and code; there is no processing done on the textarea for rendering markup.

See the answers to the question [Can I embed HTML formatting inside of a  tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580247/can-i-embed-html-formatting-inside-of-a-textarea-tag) here on stackoverflow, and possibly look into a 'What You See is What You Get' type of plugin.