# Add formatted text inside a text box in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have

```
<input type="text" />

I need to add a formatted text inside it.

$('[type=text]').html("<p class='green'>Hello World</p>")

.green {
   color: green;
   font-style: italic;
}
```

However, this does not add any green text inside it.

Comment: You can't do that. Perhaps you want a contenteditable div?

Comment: Add a class or css directly to the input box.

Comment: I can add $('[type=text]').val('Hello World'). But I want a formatted text. Can you provide some code to do that?  I want to add html inside the textbox

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I embed HTML formatting inside of a <textarea> tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580247/can-i-embed-html-formatting-inside-of-a-textarea-tag)

Comment: A textbox does not have HTML decedents, only a value property. You can style the text inside the textbox, but you can't add HTML to it.

Comment: It doesn't need to get downvoted, but you could have found this there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580247/can-i-embed-html-formatting-inside-of-a-textarea-tag (I suppose they is no difference between textarea and input)

Comment: The down votes are due to a clear lack of research.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg

Answer (score 0):

To add formatted text to a textbox

```
$('[type=textbox]').val('Hello World');
$('[type=textbox]').addClass('green');

.green{

   color: green;
}
```