# Razor Syntax: Html.Raw not working in <textarea>

Tags: asp.net, razor, textarea

I have an asp.net project where Html.Raw() is not working as expected for a textarea tag:

```
 <textarea>@(Html.Raw("<p>Test</p>"))</textarea>
```

[image: Result]

How can I get the html to render correctly?

Comment: What you're expecting? Html.Raw-Returns markup that is not HTML encoded.

Comment: @malkam What is returned in the textarea is "<p>Test</p>", but what I am expecting is "Test" where the <p> tag is formatted by css

Comment: then simply try <textarea><p>Test</p></textarea>

Comment: The string "<p>Test</p>" is formed dynamically. Trying to add "<textarea>" to the string and applying Html.Raw() to this new string has the same result

Comment: We can't have html formatted text in textarea. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580247/can-i-embed-html-formatting-inside-of-a-textarea-tag

Answer (score 5):

Your code is working as it should, but `<textarea>` elements cannot contain formatted HTML. In other words, `Html.Raw()` is doing its thing, but the browser is correctly not formatting the HTML tags inside the `<textarea>` element.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea), "character data" is the only permitted content for a `<textarea>`.

If you need something like a textarea that allows for formatted HTML, you are looking for a WYSIWYG editor, like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/), or Kendo's [Editor](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/index).