# How do I keep data in a textarea as is?

Tags: php, html

What I am trying to do is save data from a textarea as is. When I save write data into my textarea and format it as I want after I save it in my database it ignores all of what I did and saves it a plain text. For example I tried to save something like:

```
Fruit    Apple    Banana    Kiwi    Orange
Tom        1        2         0        5
Jerry      0        0         4        1
Cindy      0        0         0        8
```

But when I put them into the database they come out like this:

Fruit    Apple    Banana    Kiwi    Orange
Tom        1        2         0        5
Jerry      0        0         4        1
Cindy      0        0         0        8

I want to keep the format that I gave it at the begging.

Is it possible to add tables to it?

Comment: What's the column type?

Comment: You want to add html tag in your textarea, see some discussion here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580247/can-i-embed-html-formatting-inside-of-a-textarea-tag you can use any editor suited here http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/10-best-wysiwyg-text-and-html-editors-for-your-next-project/

Comment: varchar with 3000 characters

Comment: tables in textarea = ckeditior or tinymce

Comment: `nl2br` could be helpful. Not sure about the spaces though.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this with simple textArea. You have to use ckeditor or other editor.

[ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/download)

Comment: You can easily do this with just a `textarea` element. What the OP is describing has nothing to do with a problem with the tag.  The way they're getting the value or sending it is stripping out the spaces and new lines.