# Use html to format the output from a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, html, format, output, textarea

I am looking for a way to format the output from the JS object. I attempted to use html in line there with PersonD but it prints the html along with the text. What is the best way to address this issue?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Extension Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <p>
        Extension Search
    </p>
    </div>
    <p>
    <form autocomplete="off">
        <input id="thisSearch" type="text" placeholder="enter name">
        <button id="linkToJS">Run</button>
        <textarea id="output" name="output" wrap="hard" rows="10" readonly>
</textarea>
        <br><br>
    </form>
    </p>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var extensionList = {

            PersonA: 'This is person A ext_100',
            PersonB: 'This is person B ext_200',
            PersonC: 'This is person C ext_300 & PersonC Cell Phone ####',
            PersonD: ' \ <b>This is person D ext_400 <br> PersonD Cell Phone ####</b> \ ',

        };

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var link = 
document.getElementById('linkToJS').addEventListener("click", returnLookUp);
        });


        var returnLookUp = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var getInfo = document.getElementById("thisSearch");
            document.getElementById("output").value = 
extensionList[thisSearch.value];
        }
</script>

</html>
```

**Acceptance Criteria**
Use html to format the output from a JavaScript object.

As shown with "PersonD", I would like to use html to format my output to the text area. Based on the following response, it does not look like an option. 
[Can I embed HTML formatting inside of a <textarea> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580247/can-i-embed-html-formatting-inside-of-a-textarea-tag)

I tried printing to a div but did not have any luck.
[Can I embed HTML formatting inside of a <textarea> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580247/can-i-embed-html-formatting-inside-of-a-textarea-tag)

```
<body>
    <div>
    <p>
        Extension Search
    </p>
    </div>
    <p>
    <form autocomplete="off">
        <input id="thisSearch" type="text" placeholder="enter name">
        <button id="linkToJS">Run</button>
        <br><br>
    </form>
    <div id="output" name="output"></div>
    </p>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var extensionList = {

            PersonA: 'This is person A ext_100',
            PersonB: 'This is person B ext_200',
            PersonC: 'This is person C ext_300 & PersonC Cell Phone ####',
            PersonD: ' \ <b>This is person D ext_400 <br> PersonD Cell Phone ####</b> \ ',

        };


        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var link = 
document.getElementById('linkToJS').addEventListener("click", returnLookUp);
        });


        var returnLookUp = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var getInfo = document.getElementById("thisSearch");
            document.getElementById("output").value = 
extensionList[thisSearch.value];
        }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am looking for a way to format the output from the JS object. I attempted to use html in line there with PersonD but it prints the html along with the text.

Comment: Does the text need to go into a textarea?  Could you put it inside a <div> on the page instead?

Comment: Maybe not exactly related, but there are some bad practices. `thisSearch` seems to just pop out somewhere. Though it is defined on `window` (as an element with id), you should use `getInfo` instead. More related, in the second snippet you're setting the value of `div`, however, `value` is a custom property for a div, use `innerHTML` instead.

Comment: You need to edit the question to include your expected outcome. As it stands, there is no question here and no indication of what "*Use html to format the output from a JavaScript object*" should look like.

Comment: @LewisLockhart What is expected result of `" \ "` at beginning of `"PersonD"` property value at HTML?

Comment: I have used the " \ " before to get the html to work. I am not sure why it works but I know this function needs it: var message = {};
message.posted = function(recipientId){ 
 this.note = countyMessage[recipientId] || ' \ <font color="orange"> not added to standard queue-note list </font> \ '
 $("hr").append ( '      \
  <div id="qWarning"> \
   <p><font color="red" size=2.5 align="right"><b>'+this.note+'<br></b></font></p> \
  </div>              \
 ' );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking whether you can format text inside a `<textarea>`, then no, you cannot.  You can have text, and spaces.  Technically you can have line breaks too.

If you can describe a bit more about what you're actually trying to accomplish, possibly someone here could help you with that.  For now though, the simple answer is that richly formatted text is not allowed.

If you just want to put text inside a `<div>`, using javascript, use its .innerHTML property and set the inner HTML to your HTML string.

Comment: _"If you are asking whether you can format text inside a `<textarea>`, then no, you cannot."_ ?