# How can i add font awesome icons to a textarea as emojis

Tags: html, jquery, font-awesome

I am attemtping to insert font awesome icons as emojis inside a textarea everytime i click on an icon/emoji, but it obviously doesn't work. Is it even  possible? If so, let me know thanks

My code:

html

```
<!--list of icons to add to textarea-->
<i class="fas fa-laugh-squint"></i><i class="fa"></i><i class="fa"></i><i class="fa"></i><i class="fa"></i>
```

js

```
$('.fa').on('click', function() {
    var emoji = $(this).clone();
    $('textarea').val(emoji);
});
```

When i click on the icon it appears as

```
<i class="fas fa-laugh-squint"></i>
```

inside my textarea, and when i send it it appears as an icon.
How can i make it appear as a icon directly in the textarea?

Comment: hey thanks for the comment. I actually got pretty far since posting this question. Here's what i did: 
var emojiclass = emoji.attr('class'); //get the class of the font-awesome icon, then

$('textarea').val('<i class="'+emojiclass+'"></i>'); //this adds the icon to the textarea and i can submit the textarea and the icon shows in emoji form. 
The problem is in the textarea it shows up as <i class="fas.."</i>, so now its only an issue of hiding the string: <i class="fas.."</i> and replacing that with a font-awesome icon - which  is probably just as hard lol

Comment: (Edited) Very interesting question! [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2580247/8031896) may provide limited help.