# Replace empty lines with <p> tags in textarea and show it as HTML valid code

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

There is a textarea where someone can write a text. The text could be on multiple lines, I want to check the blank lines in the text and replace them with `<p>` tags, so the text between 2 blank lines should be wrapped in `<p>` tags.

So far it is working to check the blank lines and return a boolean if there is a blank line.

```js
function getInputValue() {
  // Selecting the input element and get its value
  var inputVal = document.getElementById('w3review').value;

  var inTxt = document.getElementById('w3review').value;
  console.log('intx: ', inTxt);

  if (inTxt.match(/^\s*\n/gm)) {
    console.log('yes, there is a blank line');
  } else {
    console.log('nope. no blank lines');
  }

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = inputVal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Enter text:</h1>
    <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="6" cols="15"> </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Convert to HTML" onclick="getInputValue()" />
    <label>HTML output:</label>
    <textarea id="output" name="w3review" rows="6" cols="15"> </textarea>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to replace the blank lines with

tags and also show it in the output as HTML, not to show it with

but with the HTML parsing of it?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT - updated to reflect the OP's requirements as noted in the comments

Simply split the textarea value at the newlines, then build a string with the portions encased in the `p` element tags - and then insert that string as the innerHTML of an output div. You cannot have html within a textarea - so the only way to do it is to create the elements - if you inspect the output div - you will see that ervery portion of the textarea input is encased in `<p>...</p>` tags - with the emty line in the textarea translating to an empty p element in the output.

[image]

```js
function getInputValue() {
  // Selecting the input element and get its value
  var inputVal = document.getElementById('w3review').value;
  
  
  const newTextPortions = inputVal.split('\n');
    
  newTextStr = ''
    newTextPortions.forEach(function(portion){
     newTextStr += "<p>" + portion + "</p>"
  })
  

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = newTextStr;
}
```

```html
    <label>Enter text</label>
    <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="15"> </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Convert to HTML" onclick="getInputValue()" />
    <div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: maybe I was not clear, I don't want to show the <p> text value in the result, I want to show it like a paragraph, for exaple if it is <i> to show the text in italic not to show the actual <i> text

Comment: oh - i see - no you cannot do that insde a textare - you will need to swap the output textarea - for a div.

Comment: I think that your code is putting a <p> tag for all new lines and it should put it only for blank lines

Comment: @LeoMessi - hi - i did that originally - but then changed it after your coments - eitehr way - it demonstrates the functionality. I was unsuere of the requirementes and so put in what I thought was required - but I am open to it being simply a reference on how to transfer the value of the textarea to a valid html element.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

use `replace` insted of `if`

```
     function getInputValue() {
  // Selecting the input element and get its value
  var inputVal = document.getElementById('w3review').value;

  var inTxt = document.getElementById('w3review').value;
  console.log('intx: ', inTxt);

  inTxt = inTxt.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
  inTxt = inTxt.replace("  "," ");


  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = inTxt;
}
```

**Long answer (Best practice):**

Create a function that sanetizes the input, creates "actual" P-tags and append them to the DOM and/or show render them in the textfield.
You can't show rich-content in the textfield, but one approach is to create a  fake-textfield -> [Format text in a <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>Enter text:</h1>
        <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="6" cols="15"> </textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Convert to HTML" onclick="getInputValue()" />
        <label>HTML output:</label>
        <textarea id="output" name="w3review" rows="6" cols="15"> </textarea>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <div id="target"> </div>
      </body>
      <script>
    
      function getInputValue() {
      // Selecting the input element and get its value
      var inputVal = document.getElementById('w3review').value;
    
      var inTxt = document.getElementById('w3review').value;
      console.log('intx: ', inTxt);
    
      inTxt = inTxt.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,",");
      let textArray = []
      let sanitizedArray = []
    
      textArray = inTxt.split(",")
      console.log(textArray)
    
      //Sanitize the array
      textArray.map((data, index)=> data === ""? console.log(`Index ${index} is empty don't push`): sanitizedArray.push(data))
      console.log(sanitizedArray)
    
      function createValidHtml(content){
        const target = document.getElementById("target")
        let pTag = document.createElement("p")
        pTag.innerHTML = content
        target.appendChild(pTag)
      }
    
      sanitizedArray.map(data => createValidHtml(data))

      //Set as value of output-textfield (if necessary)
      const target = document.getElementById("target")
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = target.innerHTML
    }
      </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use HTML instead of a textarea (as you [can't have HTML in a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580247/can-i-embed-html-formatting-inside-of-a-textarea-tag)), then you can write HTML into a div instead:

```js
function getInputValue() {
  // Selecting the input element and get its value
  var inputVal = document.getElementById('w3review').value;

  var inTxt = document.getElementById('w3review').value;
  console.log('intx: ', inTxt);

  if (inTxt.match(/^\s*\n/gm)) {
    console.log('yes, there is a blank line');
  } else {
    console.log('nope. no blank lines');
  }

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '<p>' + inTxt.replaceAll(/(\n+)/g, '</p><p>') + '</p>';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>Enter text:</h1>
  <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="6" cols="15"> </textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Convert to HTML" onclick="getInputValue()" />
  <label>HTML output:</label>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so if there can be HTML in textarea, is it a way to show the resulted text as HTML?

Comment: Yes, just not in another textarea, because those are for [text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea).